# Which STL container for Orderbook representation?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I am building an application which receives updates on price data from different currency exchanges. Now I need to choose the most efficient container. The container will use elements of type `Entry`:

```
struct Entry
{
    std::string exchange_name;
    double price;
    double amount;
}
```

The entries must be ordered by their price, ascending:

```
Ex.Name    Price    Amount
  "A"       1.2       23
  "B"       1.3       3
  "A"       1.4       1.2
  "C"       1.5       4
  "A"       1.6       2
```

There will be many insertions and removals on the container. I guess up to 200 per second are possible. The values inside the container may not be `const`, so that the amount can be changed for a specific entry.

So far I came to the conclusion that `std::list` might be a good choice, since it [allows constant time insert and erase operations anywhere within the sequence](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/).

Is `std::list` the best choice for this application or should I use another container?

Comment: The best approach is to find the potential best candidate (std::list may be good) and measure the actual performance to see if it does fit your needs.

Comment: How will you ensure ordering in the list ?  In your case insert will be O(log(n)) at best , as you need to find where to insert in the list.

Comment: http://john-ahlgren.blogspot.com/2013/10/stl-container-performance.html

Comment: `std::list` has constant time insert and erase, but you still need to iterate over the list to find the location where you want to insert/erase (and that is slow). Do you need the container to be ordered at all times, or is it OK to have it unordered and then order it only when you need to print/save/etc the container?

Comment: You have repeated entries in the example. Does that mean that you can both have repeated entries and updates to existing entries? If so, how do you tell the difference between those two?

Comment: @gurka it is ok to have the container unordered until I need to "work" with it, if that is faster.

Comment: @jdehesa Where do I have repeated entries? All entries have different prices and amounts.

Comment: @Bobface So when you said "the values inside the container may not be `const`, so that the amount can be changed for a specific entry", what does it exactly mean? I assumed it meant you could change the Price or Amount for an existing Ex.Name (that is, you have some Ex.Name with Price and Amount in your collection, then you receive a message and update its value inside of the collection).

Comment: @jdehesa Yes that is correct. Although only the amount will be changed, not the price. There will never be an entry with the same Ex.Name and price.

Answer (score 1):

Well, list insertion will be constant time, but your list should be ordered, thus, you need to find a proper insertion position first. It will take `O(N)` time!
Thus, it's much more efficient to prefer an ordered tree based container like `std::multimap`. An insertion or search will take `O(log(N))` time. Price should be the *key*.

Comment: Insertion point can be found in log(n) if the list is built in ordered way.

Comment: No! Because, unlike as  in an array, you cannot reach its median point in less than O(N) time

Comment: However displaying the list would require to first retrieve all the elements from the map, display them and then inserting them back (or sth like copying the map before emptying it), which would actually be O(N·log(N)). If the list needs to be displayed at all times it may not be a good option.

Comment: @AndreySScherbakov Thanks, i didn't thought through it properly , you are correct.

Comment: If one half-cuts a list, time complexity will be O(N) rather than O(N*log(N)), because each step search will be done over a sub-list of  exponentially decreasing size; say, you have a list of 1024 elements; first median search will take 512 iteration, the next 256, then 128 and so on. The sum of 512+256+...+ 1 = 2^k+2^(k-1)+...2^0 = 2^(k+1)-1 = 1024-1  - it's about the same as original list size (k=9 here)

Comment: Why not just std::map? You are not supposed to have the same price and different orderbook levels? I guess you are doing it this way since you will represent buys and sells in the same map instead of separating them in two different maps.